# How to figure out electron wavelength?

Tags: electrons

This is a sample question in our study guide and it has me perplexed. Any advice on how to solve it?

> In a transmission electron microscope, electrons are transmitted through a sample at around 70% the speed of light. What is the wavelength of these electrons? (This wavelength will determine the resolution of the microscope.)
>
> If you wanted to increase the resolution of the microscope, would you want to transmit the electrons faster or slower? Why?

Comment: PS i dont want the answer just how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, $\lambda = \frac{v}{f}$, where $\lambda$ is wavelength, $v$ is the speed of the wave, and $f$ is the frequency of the wave. Do you know the frequency of the wave? If you don't I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Use the de Broglie equation:

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{mv} $$

*h* is Planck's constant, *m* is the mass of the electron in kg, and *v* is the speed of the electron in m/s.